# initialization of immutable value 'rate' was never used

Tags: swift, macos

I am brand new to Swift and Xcode and I am trying to build a financial calculator for Mac and I have encountered two issues.
The first issue is that in my code, it says that I initialized a value, but never used it. I believe that I have actually done that, but I keep getting the error. Here is my entire code for the class I'm working on:
    import Cocoa

```
class PresentValueController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var answer_label: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var payment_field: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rate_field: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var periods_field: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var compounding_popup: NSPopUpButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    }

    @IBAction func popupValueChanged(_ sender: NSPopUpButton) {
        let rate = (rate_field.integerValue)/sender.selectedTag()
        return
    }

    @IBAction func calculate_button(_ sender: Any) {
        let payment = (payment_field.integerValue)
        let present_value = (payment / (1 + rate)^12)

        answer_label.stringValue = "$\(present_value)"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have defined rate and tried to use it, but I keep getting the error.

My next question has to do with aesthetics. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRUOd.png) is what I want my output to look like, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpzRr.png) is what ends up happening when I comment out the errors and run the code. Could I please get some help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You are returning just after the rate declaration, you are not using it.

Comment: **1)** Swift convention is for instance members to user lowerCamelCase, not snake_case, **2)** you have a lot of unnecessary parentheses, **3)** you should use NumberFormatter to properly format currencies, **4)** the `^` operator is bit-wise XOR, not exponentiation. You need to use `pow`, **5)** your IBAction parameter type should be the most specific type possible, never `Any`. **6)** You probably meant to use double math, not integer math, otherwise everything would be truncating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
let rate = (rate_field.integerValue)/sender.selectedTag()
```

you don't use  , you may think it's visible inside the other method but it's not , also remove the return

//

```
@IBAction func calculate_button(_ sender: Any) {
    let rate = (rate_field.integerValue)/ popButton.selectedTag()
    let payment = (payment_field.integerValue)
    let present_value = (payment / (1 + rate)^12)

    answer_label.stringValue = "$\(present_value)"
}
```

and declare

```
 @IBOutlet weak var popButton: NSPopUpButton!
```

if it's not already

```
 @IBOutlet weak var compounding_popup: NSPopUpButton!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `rate` variable is local to `popupValueChanged(_:)`, and your reference to `rate` in `calculate_button(_:)` is a reference to an undefined variable.

You *could* save `rate` as an instance variable of your `PresentValueController` objects, but I would advise against it, because you would be duplicating data, and it's easy for it to go out of sync as the complexity of your app grows.

Instead, I recommend you just compute the `rate` within your `calculate_button(_:)` function, and drop the `popupValueChanged(_:)` function completely:

```
class PresentValueController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var paymentField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var periodsField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var compoundingPopup: NSPopUpButton!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let rate = rateField.integerValue / sender.selectedTag()
        let payment = paymentField.doubleValue
        let presentValue = payment / pow(1 + Double(rate), 12)

        let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let f = NumberFormatter()
            f.locale = NSLocale.current
            f.numberStyle = .currency
            return f
        }()

        answerLabel.stringValue = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: presentValue))!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concepts of scope and local variables.

A variable (or a let constant) you define inside a function only exists inside the function. (For the rest of this post I'm going to use the term "variable", "immutable variable" and "let constant" interchangeably, even though that's a bit sloppy.)

Your function `popupValueChanged()` creates a **local** variable rate that only exists inside the function. As soon as you exit the function, the local variables you define inside the function go out of scope and cease to exist.

Based on the code you posted I would expect your function `calculate_button()` to have another error about an undefined expression `rate`.

Consider this code:

```
class AClass {
let rate = 3

func foo() {
    let rate = 6
    print("inside function, rate =", rate)
    print("inside function, self.rate = ", self.rate)
}

}

let anObject = AClass()
anObject.foo()
print("outside function, anObject.rate = ", anObject.rate)

print("rate =", rate) //This will give an error.
```

(pretend it's entered into a playground)

The code will do the following:

Create an instance of `AClass`. The initialization of the `AClass` object will create an immutable instance variable `rate` with a value of 3.

Then we call the `AClass` object's `foo()` method, which defines a different, **local** variable, also named `rate`, and assigns the value 6 to that local variable.

The output of that code will be

```
inside function, rate = 6
inside function, anObject.rate =  3
outside function, anObject.rate =  3
```

Inside the function, the local variable `rate` hides the **instance** variable rate, so referring to `rate` inside the function refers to the local immutable variable. Since there are 2 different variables named `rate` defined at different scopes, we have to use `self.rate` to refer to the **instance** variable `rate` inside the function.

Outside the `foo()` function the function's local variable `rate` no longer exists so `rate` refers to the **instance** variable rate, who's value has always been 3.

The line:

```
print("rate =", rate) //This will give an error.
```

Will give a compile error since outside the function there is no variable at that scope with the name `rate`.